Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')
I am using Vue3 app and Quasar for UI components. I implemented header and basic page styling using quasar and then wanted to have tabs within a page. Whenever i use q-tabs in component.vue file i get this error

ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')
at Proxy.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.esm.prod.js:219:143022)
at renderComponentRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:940:38)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5320:46)
at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:217:19)
at instance.update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5433:16)
at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5443:5)
at mountComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5237:7)
at processComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5203:9)
at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4878:11)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5327:11)

<template>
  <q-tabs v-model="tab" dense class="text-grey" active-color="primary" indicator-color="primary" align="justify"
    narrow-indicator>
    <q-tab name="mails" label="Mails" />
    <q-tab name="alarms" label="Alarms" />
    <q-tab name="movies" label="Movies" />
  </q-tabs>

</template>



<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      tab: ref('mails')
    }
  }
}
</script>



import { Quasar, QLayout, QPageContainer, QTabs, QTab, QTabPanels, QTabPanel } from 'quasar'
app.use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions, QLayout, QPageContainer,QTabs, QTab, QTabPanels, QTabPanel )

i am importing QTabs & QTab in main.vue. I keep getting error as soon as q-tabs/q-tab is used in .vue page which render Webpage.
using Vue3 & @quasar/cli v2.4.0
